# Can a muslim pursue his/her career in Gaming content creator on Youtube?

Tags: halal-haram, sharia, shirk, non-muslim

Assalamualaikum Warahmatullah Wabarakatuh.
I am Mohammed Abdur Rahman i am 15 years old.

I want to ask that can a muslim create a gaming channel, make videos, and earn his/her livlihood?

Like the channel name matters,
Or about video editing like content, sound effects, memes, background musics, voiceover, and about a story type video. In this things what things will be haram or halal.

And what type of video games will be haram or halal or promote shirk. Video games like horror games, story games, survival games, adventurous games, fighting or killing games like freefire etc.

And if i add some reminders for salahs and tell some hadith etc at end will this make the video entertaining and educational and non time wasting? And what if other religion peoples wathches my videos, should i also tell them to do their religious work?

About voice i don't like to talk disrespectively and hurt anyone.

And about memes it will be jokes on me only not on the audience.

And about background music there will be no lyrics like some calm, intense, happy, sad etc type of music according to the situation but doesn't contain lyrics.

I play minecraft and want to make a story type series in which it contains evilness shadows magics dakrness etc but with good endings and vicory of good etc. Will this make the story halal or haram?

But mainly about games, what type of games will be haram, if it contain curse language or inappropriate content like that if i skip that or do something to don't se it will that considered as halal?

Because i want to play games and upload on youtube and earn by monetizing my channel. And what about ads will that haram? Or should i spend some percent as sadqah to make the amount halal?